# Identity Server 4 Client Works Even If Server Down

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have 2 separate services - some asp.net core service(let's call if FooService) and security service with identity server 4 installed (let's call it IdentityService)

On FooService I use Identity Server 4 AccessTokenValidation:

```
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("IdentityService",
                options =>
                {
                    options.JwtValidationClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero;
                    options.Authority = $"http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Jwt;
                });
```

And after it starts, if the IdentityServer is down, JWT could not be validated, because it doesnt find IdnetityServer4 endpoints on address `options.Authority = $"http://localhost:5000` - its normal behavior.

But there could be a situation, when IdentityServer is still Up, it created JWT and FooService validated some of them - and then IdentityServer  goes down - FooService still works with these JWT, that are not still expired. Also, it successfully validates **valid** tokens, but that first appeared in request. Its like, identity server 4 client caches auth scheme or smth.

I tried to play with some settings and parameters:

```
 options.SaveToken = false;
 options.BackChannelTimeouts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
 options.CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
 options.EnableCaching = false;
 options.BackChannelTimeouts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
 options.DiscoveryDocumentRefreshInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
```

But it still works with IdentityServer down.

Is there any way to stop validating JWT's when IdentityServer is down? Like to force it validating tokens everytome using authority urls? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By detault JwtBearer via the Configuration manager caches the signing keys for 24 hours. in .NET this is configurable via:

.AddMyJwtBearer(opt =>
{
opt.AutomaticRefreshInterval = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);   //1 day

```
 opt.BackchannelTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10); //10 seconds 
 ...
```

}

The alternative is to reduce the lifetime of the access tokens.

If the Configuration manager can't reload new signing keys, it will try again every 30 seconds and it will keep using the existing keys, until new keys can be loaded.

Like what this slide from one of my training classes shows:

[image]